# Redirecting www.foo.example.com to foo.example.com

Tags: dns, cpanel, cname

I have a Cpanel web hosting account and have created a subdomain which redirects to an IP address of a different server (Windows IIS) by creating an A record. I don't have control of the Windows server.

I would like that those people who type `www.` before the subdomain get redirected to the same page.

I tried creating a CNAME record pointing www.foo.example.com. to foo.example.com but it isn't working. It is actually stopping the A record from working.

How do I redirect www.foo.example.com. to foo.example.com in Cpanel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your cPanel *may* have an interface to do that for you. What needs to be done, which is what such interface would do anyway, is modifying the .htaccess file in your public_html directory. It will add the following lines:

```
RewriteEngine ON

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.foo.example.com$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://foo.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Omit the RewriteEngine ON line if it is already there.

Comment: This does not work in my case since foo.example.com points to another server.

Comment: @ToDo - Have you tried? I have cross-server redirects like this which work for top-level domains, so I do not see why it wouldn't work for a sub-domain. Are you sure your DNS are set correctly?

Comment: Yes I did try. I cannot put the .htaccess on the host where the site is. It is a Windows IIS server that I don't have control of.

Comment: @ToDo - Oh. I am confused. You need to redirect from IIS to Apache? The question made me think it was the other way around since I've only seen cPanel on Apache servers which is the one that uses .htaccess files.

Comment: No I need to redirect the subdomain from Apache to IIS and www.subdomain to subdomain.

Comment: @ToDo - The redirecting .htaccess file needs to be on the Apache server. That is where the request is sent and the broswer will get a 301 Permanent Redirection response and then request the new subdomain URL. You have just to make sure that the DNS entries for the domain and subdomain point to their intended destination.

Comment: OK I understood. foo.example.com is redirected through an A record and www.foo.example.com is redirected through a 301 Permanent redirection.

Comment: This works if you remove the `$1` in the second line.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these 2 steps in order to achieve the same.

Step 1) Delete the CNAME record that is redirecting(at the DNS Level) www.foo.example.com to foo.example.com.

In order to do this, You will have to log-in to the Advanced DNS Zone editor present in your cPanel and delete the following CNAME record: www.foo.example.com IN CNAME foo.example.com.

Step 2) You will have to add an A record pointing foo.example.com pointing to the concerned IP address.(IPv4 or IPv6).

The A record will be similar to this:
foo.example.com IN A x.x.x.x

where x.x.x.x is the IP address assigned by your web hosting provider.

Comment: The cname record is pointing in the opposite direction: www.foo.example.com -> foo.example.com

Comment: The A record is already set. Deleting the CNAME record makes the www.foo.example.com give a 404 error.

Comment: Creating two A records is not my question. I want that when a user enters www.foo.example.com he gets redirected to foo.example.com.

Comment: You can use .htaccess.

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]